# How to auto-complete based on the buffer contents in tmux?

Tags: shell, tmux

Sometimes there is on-screen text you want to enter, and copy-pasting isn't all that fast.

Is there a way to auto-complete text on the command line, based on the buffer content?

Comment: see also extrakto tmux plugin from user laktak, in their [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/405342/119298)

Answer (score 6):

### Fish Shell

`fzf-complete-from-tmux.sh`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
tmux capture-pane -pS -100000 |      # Dump the tmux buffer.
  tac |                              # Reverse so duplicates use the first match.
  pcregrep -o "[\w\d_\-\.\/]+" |     # Extract the words.
  awk '{ if (!seen[$0]++) print }' | # De-duplicate them with awk, then pass to fzf.
  fzf --no-sort --exact +i           # Pass to fzf for completion.
```

Example binding with the fish shell.

```bsh
# Ctrl-N: Complete based on the tmux buffer content.
bind \cn "commandline -i (fzf-complete-from-tmux.sh) 2>/dev/null"
```

### Bash Shell

Added bash version thanks to @juanitocalero.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

__screen-autocomplete__() {
    tmux capture-pane -pS -100000 |      # Dump the tmux buffer.
      tac |                              # Reverse so duplicates use the first match.
      grep -P -o "[\w\d_\-\.\/]+" |      # Extract the words.
      awk '{ if (!seen[$0]++) print }' | # De-duplicate them with awk, then pass to fzf.
      fzf --no-sort --exact +i           # Pass to fzf for completion.
}

__screen_autocomplete-inline__() {
    local selected="$(__screen-autocomplete__)"
    READLINE_LINE="${READLINE_LINE:0:$READLINE_POINT}$selected${READLINE_LINE:$READLINE_POINT}"
    READLINE_POINT=$(( READLINE_POINT + ${#selected} ))
}

# Example binding with bash shell.
bind -x '"\C-n": "__screen_autocomplete-inline__"'
```

Comment: What is 'commandline -i' ?

Comment: I've used: `bind-key $KEY send-keys "$PATHTOSCRIPT/fzf-complete-from-tmux.sh" Enter`

Comment: Inserts the text - https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#commandline

Comment: I 've extended this wonderful script to be launched in bash with Ctrl-N, and include the output in the same line: https://github.com/juanitocalero/.dotfiles/blob/master/bashrc.d/screen-autocomplete.bashrc (must be `source`d)

Comment: Thanks, updated the answer.